# Control Spacing along PathView QML

Tags: qml

I'm trying to animate 5 elements along the following path:
[image: Animation Path]

I would like to place each element at the points specified in the diagram. I would also probably put a buffer item at 0% and 100% in order to prevent items from flashing out instead of animating off screen. I am currently using a PathView approach, and I have specified a path with the starting point at 0%, and the end point at 100%. However, I cannot control the distribution of the elements. I was wondering if PathView is the correct approach, and how it would be implemented.

Comment: I've never used it, but this sounds promising https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pathpercent.html

Comment: This requires for you to create the midpoints yourself, and to insert the percentages between them (which is not really required anymore since you already created the points)

Comment: I didn't quite understand the *buffer* thing, but the elements would distribute along the path if you use a [PathAngleArc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pathanglearc.html) and [pathItemCount](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pathview.html#pathItemCount-prop) to determine the number of visible items along the path. Additionally, you can set [preferredHighlightBegin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pathview.html#preferredHighlightBegin-prop)/End to center the items. In your case, the result would match the image you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found is to use [PathAngleArc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pathanglearc.html) QML object, and to use [preferredHighlightBegin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pathview.html#preferredHighlightBegin-prop) and end to control the centering.

Source: Comment on the main post by user "smr"

Comment: It is polite to mention where you got the answer instead of just copy-pasting it.